# change of variable for Lp norm of the gradient of a function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For $v\in H^{1}_0(B_R(0))$ with $B_R(0)$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ we define the following function,
$$\phi(r) = \int_{B_r(0)} |\nabla_x v(x)|^p dx$$
where $r\leq R.$ I want to check if the expression I have derived for the change of variable $x=ry$ is correct.

Using $dx = r^2 dy$ we get,
$$\phi(r) = \int_{B_1(0)} |\nabla_{ry} v(ry)|^p r^2 dy.$$
Now,
$$\nabla_{ry} v(ry) = r^{-1} \nabla_y v(ry)$$
and therefore,
$$\phi(r) = r^{2-p}\int_{B_1(0)} |\nabla_{y} v(ry)|^p dy.$$
Is this correct?

Comment: What is $y$ in your work?

Comment: @Rem $y$ is the new variable with respect to which I want to integrate.

Comment: By setting $x=ry$, aren't you only integrating on the circle though?

Comment: @Rem yes indeed

Comment: @Rem, the map $y \mapsto ry$ is a bijection (even a diffeomorphism) between $B_{1}(0)$ and $B_{r}(0)$.

Comment: @PeterMorfe True. I didn't think of it this way, I was assuming $y$ to be a unit vector.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct.

Notice the factor you get $r^{2 - p}$ came in two separate parts: the $r^{2}$ factor and the $r^{-p}$ one.

An easy way to think of the normalization $r^{2}$ is it's what you need to average by to get the right answer (when there are no derivatives around).  For example, if $u : B_{r}(0) \to \mathbb{R}$ and if I define $u_{r} : B_{1}(0) \to \mathbb{R}$ just by rescaling, then the integrals change but the *average* doesn't.  (Maybe that's not super intuitive, but a nice check is that the average of a constant is always just the constant, no matter the domain.)  In other words,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{|B_{r}(0)|} \int_{B_{r}(0)} u(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{|B_{1}(0)|} \int_{B_{1}(0)} u_{r}(y) \, dy = \frac{1}{|B_{1}(0)|} \int_{B_{1}(0)} u(ry) \, dy.
\end{equation*}
Since $|B_{r}(0)| = r^{2} |B_{1}(0)|$, if we remember this idea about the averages, then we know how to relate the integrals.

The same thing applies when we look at the derivative, except that if we're looking at $\nabla_{y}u_{r}$, there's a factor of $r$ in the mix.  That's because the derivative is "rise over run" (at least in some direction): replacing $u$ by $u_{r}$ changes the "run" by a factor $r$ without changing the rise at all.  Hence $\nabla_{y}u_{r}(y) = r^{-1} \nabla_{x} u(x)$ with $x = ry$.

If you don't like seeing the $r^{-p}$, a solution is to consider the averaged norm in either case.  We get:
\begin{equation*}
\|\nabla_{y} u_{r}\|_{L^{p}_{\text{av}}(B_{1}(0))} = r^{-1} \|\nabla_{x} u\|_{L^{p}_{\text{av}}(B_{r}(0))}.
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\|\nabla_{y} u_{r}\|_{L^{p}_{\text{av}}(B_{1}(0))} := \left( \frac{1}{|B_{1}(0)|} \int_{B_{1}(0)} \|\nabla_{y} u_{r}(y) \|^{p} \, dy \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
\|\nabla_{x} u\|_{L^{p}_{\text{av}}(B_{r}(0))} := \left( \frac{1}{|B_{r}(0)|} \int_{B_{r}(0)} \|\nabla_{x} u(x)\|^{p} \, dx \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.
\end{equation*}
What's nice about this is it gets us back to the $\nabla_{y} u_{r} = r^{-1} \nabla_{x} u$ picture.

Comment: Understood thank you for your answer. In general, if $\nabla_{f(x)}g(x) = \nabla_{x} g(f^{-1}(x))$ right?

Comment: I don't understand your notation $\nabla_{f(x)}$.